# Child Re-rendering and fetching API twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, rendering

I have an issue with an application I'm working on In NextJs(13.0.4) with React(18.2.0)

I have an parent component this component is rendered once. I have also check if selectedTab is changing, with the help of useEffect.

```
const OrganizationForms = ({ selectedTab }: { selectedTab: string }) => {
  return selectedTab === 'Members' && <Members /> ||
    selectedTab === 'Invites' && <Invites /> ||
    selectedTab === 'Roles & Permissions' && <RolesAndPermissions /> ||
    <div>Not Found</div>;
};
```

The issue comes into its children

```
function Invites() {

  console.log('component mounted');
  const { organization, invites } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.organization,
  ) as {
    organization: OrganizationStateDto;
    invites: OrganizationInvitesStateDto;
  };
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {
    data,
    hasLoaded,
    loading,
    page,
    total,
  } = invites;

  const [isInviteEditFormOpen, setIsInviteEditFormOpen] = useState<string | boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    organization?.data?._id &&
    organizationInvitesActions.getInvites(
      organization?.data?._id,
      false,
    )(dispatch);
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

console.log of this function is logged twice or trice. useEffect is called twice.
I have tried to resolve it using useMemo, useCallback.

So far I have tried to isolate the child component.

I have used useCallback

```
const fetchList = useCallback(() => {
  organization?.data?._id &&
    organizationInvitesActions.getInvites(
      organization?.data?._id,
      false,
    )(dispatch);
}, [dispatch, organization?.data?._id]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect called');
  fetchList();
}, [fetchList]);
```

but nothing has helped so far

Comment: Once your component has loaded data via **getInvites**, is there any reason for it to re-load the data? If not, add a dependencies array to useEffect, and within the function inside useEffect add a conditional IF statement to prevent further dispatch calls if data were already loaded.